# Lazy initialization of cache with Spring IBatis

Tags: spring, caching, lazy-initialization

We are moving our legacy implementation to Spring IBatis model. I am kind of stuck in modeling these objects in cleaner way using Spring model

Lets say I have two classes [ Both of them are **singleton** ]

*DAOImpl*  implements *DAOInterface*

*CacheDAOImpl* implements *DAOInterface*

Code snippet showing object initialization in **CacheDAOImpl**

```
.....

private static CacheDAOImpl ourInstance = new CacheDAOImpl();

public static CacheDAOImpl  getInstance()
{
   return ourInstance;
}

private CacheDAOImpl()
{
 // intialiazes all caches
}
```

Code snippet from **DAOImpl** showing the **CacheDAOImpl** Object usage

```
private DAO getCacheDAO()
{
   return CacheDAOImpl.getInstance();
}

@Override
public SomeObject lookUpId()
{
  return getCacheDAO().lookUpId();
}
```

In the above implementation cache is initialized only when an method is invoked in DAOImpl whereas with Spring model of initialization, can we do this?. lazy-init may not work here as the object DAOImpl will always be accessed by non-lazy bean

Answer (score 0):

First, spring's way of defining an object as singleton is to define in the `singleton` (which is default) bean scope.

Second, `lazy-init` should work. Just make the process of initialization the DAO bean differ from the process of using it. I.e. when it is constructed, don't initialize the cache - only when it's methods are called.

Comment: @Bozho Thanks. It will be accessed by non-lazy bean always. I will edit the post for clarity.